# CSS Stylus color functions, how unit-sensitivity works?

Tags: css, stylus

I read in the documentation of Stylus CSS preprocessor language, that the color function are **unit-sensitive**. For example:

> darken(color, amount)
>
> Darken the given color by amount.This function is unit-sensitive, for
>   example supporting percentages as shown below.

Here is a code example which goes with the above function:

```
darken(#D62828, 30)
// => #551010

darken(#D62828, 30%)
// => #961c1c
```

What I don't understand, is how the first example, which has the amount of 30, was calculated. What does the amount **30** represent as a unit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, that's far from intuitive, but if you'd look into the source then you'll find out:

1. [`darken` bif](https://github.com/LearnBoost/stylus/blob/master/lib/functions/index.styl#L127) calls the `adjust` bif like this: `adjust(color, 'lightness', - amount)`
2. [`adjust` bif](https://github.com/LearnBoost/stylus/blob/master/lib/functions/index.js#L1440) have different behaviour for percents and other units:

   - When there is a unit like `30` it would change the color's lightness by reducing it by given amount from the color's lightness.
   - When there is a percent, then it would reduce its lightness by the given percent of the initial color's lightness.